# how to pass values from jsp to hibernite

Tags: hibernate, jsp

```
   <html>
 <head>
  <title>Registration form </title>
  <script>



 <form name="register" onsubmit="return validateForm()" action='register.jsp' method='get'>
<table>
<tr><td><font face="Times New Roaman">First Name*:</font></td><td><input type='text' name='fname' maxlength='30'></td></tr>
<tr><td><font face="Times New Roaman">Middle Name:</font></td><td><input type='text' name='mname' maxlength='30'></td></tr>
<tr><td><font face="Times New Roaman">Last Name*:</font></td><td><input type='text' name='lname' maxlength='30'></td></tr>
<tr><td><font face="Times New Roaman">Date of birth*</font></td>
<td><select name='date'>
<option value='0'>DD</option>

</select>

<select name='month'>
<option value='0'>MM</option>

</select>
<select name='year'>
<option value='0'>YYYY</option>

</select>
</td></tr>

<tr><td><font face="Times New Roaman">Mobile Number*</font></td><td><input type='text'  name='mob' value='10 digit' onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '10 digit';}" 
 onfocus="if (this.value == '10 digit') {this.value = '';}" maxlength='10'></td></tr>
<tr><td><font face="Times New Roaman">Email Address*</font></td><td><input type='text' name='email' value='example@domain.com' onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'example@domain.com';}"
 onfocus="if (this.value == 'example@domain.com') {this.value = '';}"></td></tr>
<tr><td><font face="Times New Roman">Address*</font></td><td><textarea rows="4" name="address"></textarea></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td><input type='submit' value='submit'><input type='reset' value='reset'></td></tr>

</table>
</form>  
 </body>
</html>
```

dont think of this code when i enter the values in jsp page it is calling a another page called register.jsp the code of that is given below how i can pss it for a hibernate program which is used to insert values in to the data base

```
<html>
<body>
<%@page import="devmanuals.model.UserDao"%>
<jsp:useBean id="link" scope="application" class = "devmanuals.model.User" />

<% 


String fname=request.getParameter("fname");
String lname=request.getParameter("lname");
String mobile=request.getParameter("mob");
String email=request.getParameter("email");
out.print("Welcome "+fname);

int i=UserDao.register(link);
if(i>0)
{
    out.println("sucessfully registered");
}

%>
```

when i using the above code it is showing error other than this how can we pass values to the hibernate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here in second `JSP`, You are creating bean for `User` but not populating it's properties using your bean's getter and setter methods with your `request`'s attributes, and this may be the cause of the `error`.

For using Model Objects in hibernate it must have `getter and setter methods` for it's properties in class.

below is sample illustration.

```
link.setXxx(request.getParameter("xxx"));
. 
.
.
int i=UserDao.register(link);
```

Aanother option is

```
<jsp:setProperty name="link" property="*" />
```

All bean properties whose names match the request parameter names -if any- will be set

[This](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_examples.htm) is a link to the example  which will explain you How to insert data into tables using Hibernate in details.